# Error: AnchorError occurred. Error Code: InstructionFallbackNotFound. Error Number: 101. Error Message: Fallback functions are not supported)

Tags: anchor, web3.js, solana-wallet-adapter, anchor-lang, anchor-program-idl

I am building an app on Solana using Anchor, and everything works when I'm testing on localnet, but whenever I switch to devnet, I'm getting the error when I call any program method. `Error: AnchorError occurred. Error Code: InstructionFallbackNotFound. Error Number: 101. Error Message: Fallback functions are not supported)`.

I have looked at related posts with the same error and nothing's working, including deleting the `target/` directory and rebuilding (my IDL looks correct), and downgrading my anchor-lang and @coral-xyz/anchor versions.

I would really appreciate any help. Thanks!

Here is some of my code (everything that I think will be useful). Let me know if you're curious about any of my other files.
I am using `anchor-lang = 0.29.0` and `"@coral-xyz/anchor": "^0.29.0"`

lib.rs:

```
#[program]
pub mod auction_space {
    use super::*;

    pub fn new_publisher(ctx: Context<NewPublisher>) -> Result<()> {
        instructions::handle_new_publisher(ctx)
    }

    pub fn new_advertiser(ctx: Context<NewAdvertiser>) -> Result<()> {
        instructions::handle_new_advertiser(ctx)
    }
    etc...
}
```

instructions/new_advertiser.rs:

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use crate::state::*;

pub fn handle_new_advertiser(ctx: Context<NewAdvertiser>) -> Result<()> {
    let advertiser = &mut ctx.accounts.advertiser;
    advertiser.advertiser_wallet = ctx.accounts.advertiser_wallet.key();
    advertiser.bump = ctx.bumps.advertiser;
    Ok(())
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct NewAdvertiser<'info> {
    #[account(
        init, 
        payer = advertiser_wallet, 
        space = ADVERTISER_SIZE,
        seeds = [b"advertiser", advertiser_wallet.key().as_ref()],
        bump
    )]
    pub advertiser: Account<'info, Advertiser>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub advertiser_wallet: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

Client code calling my program (using `@solana/wallet-adapter-react`)

```
async newPublisher() {
  const { connection } = useConnection();
  const wallet = useWallet();
  const provider = new AnchorProvider(connection, wallet as 
    AnchorWallet, {
      commitment: 'confirmed',
    });
  const program = new Program(AuctionSpaceIDL, program.programId, provider);
  const [publisherPDA, _] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
    [Buffer.from("publisher"), wallet.publicKey.toBuffer()],
    program.programId
  )
  return this.program.methods.newPublisher()
  .accounts({
    publisherWallet: this.wallet.publicKey,
    publisher: publisherPDA,
  })
  .rpc()
}
```

Anchor.toml

```
[features]
skip-lint = false

[programs.devnet]
auction_space = MY_PROGRAM_ID

[registry]
url = "https://api.apr.dev"

[provider]
cluster = "devnet"
wallet = "~/.config/solana/id.json"

[scripts]
test = "npx ts-mocha -p ./tsconfig.json -t 1000000 tests/**/*.ts"

[test.validator]
bind_address = "127.0.0.1"

[test]
startup_wait = 100000
```

Cargo.toml in program directory:

```
[package]
name = "auction-space"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "Created with Anchor"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib", "lib"]
name = "auction_space"

[features]
no-entrypoint = []
no-idl = []
no-log-ix-name = []
cpi = ["no-entrypoint"]
default = []

[dependencies]
anchor-lang = "0.29.0"
spl-token = "4.0.0"
```

Comment: This might be a simple question, but did you deploy the new program to devnet before trying to call it?

Comment: @JonC Yes I did, and I checked on the Solana Explorer to make sure it deployed properly.